# Can I use Keyboard Shortcuts to implement text macros?

Tags: keyboard

I know that Autokey has the functionality to create text macros, but I found it very buggy, and there are no new releases coming out. (IronAHK looks to be an excellent alternative, but it isn't actually available yet.)

So I'd like to do the following myself: map control-L to this (yes, just type a bunch of dashes - I'm starting simple) -

"---------------"

Can I do this via the Keyboard Shortcuts? Would an .sh script work best? And if so, can you point me in the right direction for learning how to create that kind of .sh script?

If this is a silly solution, is there an alternative program that would allow me to map text macros?

Thanks so much.

Comment: FWIW, Autokey has been resurrected and now lives at https://github.com/autokey/autokey.

Answer (score 2):

I know of 2 others:
[xmacro!](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/) [Package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=xmacro) Can not find a screenshot of this one :+)
[xnee](http://www.gnu.org/software/xnee/) [Package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=xnee)

[image: xnee]

But as with autokey... both have their quirks too.

edit: On rereading your q: these to are to create macros but autokey seems to use python scripts. So my answer might not be correct.