# Why is there a delay when typing certain characters with xdotool in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, xdotool

Using `xdotool type` or `xdotool key` with certain characters makes Gnome Shell lock up. For example typing a single slash with `xdotool type /` or `xdotool key slash` takes a second or two, but for something like 23 slashes (i.e. `xdotool type ///////////////////////`) it's more than 25 seconds.

Of all the printable ASCII characters, only these cause the problem:

- slash `/`
- backslash `\`
- bar `|`
- bracketleft `[`
- bracketright `]`
- braceleft `{`
- braceright `}`

Outside ASCII, I've only tested `çé°†`, but they also cause the problem.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

#### More details

I never had this problem in Unity on 14.04.

There is a small delay when typing other characters, but only up to a second, even for long strings.

Any timing I've done in the terminal has come back normal, like `time xdotool type ...` or `t=$SECONDS; xdotool ...; echo $((SECONDS-t))`, so it seems to be a problem on Gnome Shell's side.

I've confirmed `$XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is `x11`.

Comment: p.s. I would also appreciate any related links or simple alternatives to xdotool.

Comment: Does `setxkbmap us` fix the problem?: https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/49 Related to using this "bug fix" is .5 second delay: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139959/type-some-text-with-xdotool-independently-of-the-keyboard-layout

Comment: @Win That fixes the problem for ASCII characters but not for others like `é°`

Comment: @Win Thanks btw! I also noticed [a](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/231) [bunch](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/10) [of](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/125) [bugs](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/149) that seems to be related.

Comment: you helped me almost since my first question posted here. Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: Update: I'm switching to AutoKey

Comment: Nice. One of my first posts was about AutoKey: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866619/how-do-i-setup-keyboard-macros/866629#866629