# Wants to create keybord shortcut to paste some sentence

Tags: keyboard

I want to create keybord shortcut for paste some sentence

Ex. I'll use this sentence daily is :- my name is xyz

And want to paste this sentence in anyware with help of clt+alt+m

So how can i do ?

In Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I setup keyboard macros?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866619/how-do-i-setup-keyboard-macros)