# Remapping Caps Lock to the 'backslash' character

Tags: remapping, capslock

As I am writing a lot of LaTeX, I'd like the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to instead print a <kbd>\</kbd> (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> on my keyboard). I am running Ubuntu 23.10.

I installed `gnome-tweaks`, which allowed me to remap Caps Lock to something like Hyper, and then I ran `xcape -e 'Hyper_L=backslash'`. I then switched from Wayland to Xorg. However, two issues arose:

1. this instead prints the underscore <kbd>_</kbd> character, and
2. it does it very slowly, there is about a one second delay before the character gets printed.

I eventually tried installing AutoKey, but it just remaps keyboard shortcuts to text (solely typing a special key alone won't do anything, it needs a letter as well). I tried remapping the <kbd>Hyper</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to a backslash, but nothing was being printed.

How can I perform this modification?

Alternatively, I could instead remap the <kbd>²</kbd> key to the <kbd>\</kbd> character, but this seems like it will be even more difficult due to the special nature of that key?

Comment: Have you tried `input-mapper-gtk`?

Comment: @DanielT I just installed this and configured it. It is still slow (maybe due to Xorg? I see it works on Wayland, I'll try), and this time it prints asterisks instead of backslashes!

Comment: I have an input-remapper-gtk Wayland answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1503977/1004020

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielT, that worked just fine once I sat down and worked it out!